# Executing a command on Checkbox.Checked or Unchecked

Tags: wpf, mvvm, checkbox, command

I have a checkbox control on a window. I'd like to execute a command that will call a method in the associated view model. I'll also need the value of the checkbox as well. I cannot seem to find a way to associate a command with a checkbox. Has anyone done this?

Comment: just have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959431/how-do-i-attach-commands-to-the-checking-and-unchecking-of-a-checkbox

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox"
          Command="{Binding YourCommand}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Comment: ... and bind CommandParameter to CheckBox's value using RelativeSource.Self

Comment: ... and bind CommandParameter to CheckBox's value using `CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay}`

Comment: I assume that the command must implement ICommand? It worked for me with that (I didn't try anything else).

Comment: @Wally in your comment, you forgot the closing double quotes in the end :)

Comment: @MaratKhasanov and I need to convert the object to type checkbox to get the value of Checked? or the binding to Self will give me the value of Checked?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou, a long long time ago)) Wally had given the right binding in the comment below mine

Comment: I found it after I commented but forgot to delete the comment :-)

Comment: @JohnDemetriou no problem ;)

Comment: How to get Content also in the model code? I have multiple checkboxes and I need to know which text was checked.

Answer (score 32):

If you use MVVM, you can use event triggers like this:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ServiceOrderItemTask.IsCompleted, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding ServiceOption.Name}">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                 <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.IsCompletedCheckedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type t:RadGridView}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
           </i:EventTrigger>

           <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                 <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.IsCompletedUncheckedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type t:RadGridView}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
           </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: excellent, but in order to use this you need these namespaces in your XAML:
 `xmlns:t="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"` `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`

Comment: and how is that implemented in the viewmodel?

Comment: @gts13 In VM, you have 2 commands 'IsCompletedCheckedCommand' and IsCompletedUncheckedCommand' which point to the relevant methods.

Comment: this approach requires [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/open-sourcing-xaml-behaviors-for-wpf/) (.NET Framework 4.5, VS2019+)

Answer (score 15):

This will work what you requires -

```
<CheckBox CommandParameter="{Binding}"
          Command="{Binding DataContext.YourCommand,
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                           AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
          Content="{Binding Path=Name}">
```

Comment: Nice trick! It even works when such `CheckBox` has `IsChecked`-binding to a model, so you can trace the model changes without hooking on `INotifyPropertyChanged`, which is quite handy when you have lot checkboxes in a collection.

Answer (score 5):

- Add `System.Windows.Interactivity` to your project references.
- Add `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"` to your XAML namespaces.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding SomeBoolProperty, Mode=OneWay}" Content="Check Meee!">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyOnCheckedCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyOnUncheckedCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
```

I implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on my ViewModel as follows:

```cs
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged(string name) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
```

The `SomeBoolProperty` of my ViewModel then looks like this:

```cs
private bool _SomeBoolProperty = false;
public bool SomeBoolProperty { 
    get => _SomeBoolProperty;
    set { 
        _SomeBoolProperty = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SomeBoolProperty)); 
    } 
}
```

I use RelayCommand as my command implementation from here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22286816/336753.

The commands on my ViewModel then look like this:

```cs
public ICommand MyOnCheckedCommand { get; } = new RelayCommand(o => {
    // Do something here.
    SomeBoolProperty = true;
});
public ICommand MyOnUncheckedCommand { get; } = new RelayCommand(o => {
    // Do something else here.
    SomeBoolProperty = false;
});
```

---

I got to this question trying to find a way to **reuse** two commands I already had on my ViewModel. One called when checked and one when unchecked. I use them on some buttons too so did not want to add an extra parametrized command. People were asking here about ViewModel implementation so adding this answer to complete the one from [Igor_S](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15249090/336753). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late... I used Rohit Vats answer and came up with this code.

The example is a working code extract and it is only here to help to understand every aspects. It is a pushpin that could be either active or inactive and it use a DelegateCommand. You could probably also use a RelayCommand or any other similar class to do the same job.

Command:

```
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace HQ.Wpf.Util.Command
{
    public class StandardCommand
    {
        public static RoutedUICommand PinPropertyGrid = new RoutedUICommand("Pin property grid", "PinPropertyGrid", typeof(StandardCommand));
```

Xaml:

```
                            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                      Margin="2,0,3,0" 
                                      Command="{Binding CommandPinPropertyGrid}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                                <CheckBox.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Image x:Name="ImagePushpin" Width="16" Height="16" Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfUtil;component/Images/PushpinUnpinned16x16.png" />
                                        </Grid>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                                <Setter TargetName="ImagePushpin" Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/WpfUtil;component/Images/PushpinPinned16x16.png" />
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </CheckBox.Template>
                            </CheckBox>
```

Model:

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    CommandPinPropertyGrid = new DelegateCommand<bool>(PinPropertyGrid);
```

...

```
// ******************************************************************
public DelegateCommand<bool> CommandPinPropertyGrid { get; private set; }

public void PinPropertyGrid(bool pinned)
{
    this.IsPropertyGridPinned = pinned;
}
```

DelegateCommand:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace HQ.Wpf.Util.Command
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a command that forwards the <c>Execute</c> and <c>CanExecute</c> calls to specified delegates.
    /// </summary>
    public class DelegateCommand<T> : ICommand
    {

        private readonly Action<T> _executeCallback;
        private readonly Predicate<T> _canExecuteCallback;

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // OBJECT
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DelegateCommand<T>"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="executeCallback">The execute callback delegate.</param>
        public DelegateCommand(Action<T> executeCallback)
            : this(executeCallback, null)
        {
            // No-op
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DelegateCommand<T>"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="executeCallback">The execute callback delegate.</param>
        /// <param name="canExecuteCallback">The can execute callback delegate.</param>
        public DelegateCommand(Action<T> executeCallback, Predicate<T> canExecuteCallback)
        {
            if (executeCallback == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("executeCallback");

            this._executeCallback = executeCallback;
            this._canExecuteCallback = canExecuteCallback;
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // INTERFACE IMPLEMENTATION
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        #region ICommand Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Defines the method that determines whether the command can execute in its current state.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parameter">Data used by the command.  If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to <see langword="null"/>.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// <c>true</c> if this command can be executed; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </returns>
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return (this._canExecuteCallback == null) ? true : this._canExecuteCallback((T)parameter);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when changes occur that affect whether or not the command should execute.
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                if (this._canExecuteCallback != null)
                    CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                if (this._canExecuteCallback != null)
                    CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Defines the method to be called when the command is invoked.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parameter">Data used by the command.  If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to <see langword="null"/>.</param>
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this._executeCallback((T)parameter);
        }

        #endregion // ICommand Members

    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

When you need only the Status of the CheckBox (Checked or Unchecked), then you don't need a Parameter. You can detect the Status of the Checkbox when you use this code:

```
CheckBox box = e.OriginalSource as CheckBox;

if(box.IsChecked.Value)
    DoThis();
else
    DoAnotherMethod();
```

"e" is the ExecutedRoutedEventArgs-Parameter in the Command. You Need box.IsChecked.Value, because box.IsChecked is from Type bool?.