# I want to catch checked event defined in a Datatemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

i have a ResourceDictionary where i have this code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UserDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=MyPhoto}" Height="100"/>
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Path=Names}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <CheckBox x:Name="chkBxRegistered" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>        
    </DataTemplate>
```

in my xaml file i have:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="UserList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserDataTemplate}" Grid.Column="1">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </ItemsControl>
```

and i bind my list on this way

UserList.ItemsSource = result;  //List  result
 so, in my code Behind i want to catch checked event and do all the logic i need or if anyone have another idea please comment and help me, thanks and sorry for my bad english .

Comment: Can you not use binding for `IsChecked` and `Command` properties on `Checkbox`, to achieve what you are trying? Check accepted answer for this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566050/executing-a-command-on-checkbox-checked-or-unchecked).

Comment: the problem is that i'm not using MVVM :(

Comment: I see, you use Binding in your DataTemplate, you can have properties for IsChecked and Command binding wherever you currently have MyPhoto, Names properties.

Comment: you mean some like that:

<DataTemplate x:Key="UserDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=MyPhoto}" Height="100"/>
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Path=Names}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <CheckBox x:Name="chkBxRegistered" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Checked="isChecked_Checked"/>
        </StackPanel>        
    </DataTemplate>

Comment: No. something like this: `<CheckBox Command="{Binding CheckedCommand}" CommandParameter="{RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}" />` Also, post your code where you have Names, and MyPhoto defined (xaml.cs?)

Comment: ok, then i need to add the follow property in my class in order to work that code? 
public bool? IsChecked { get; set; }
or i need something else?

Answer (score 0):

Considering I do not know how your xaml.cs looks like, the easiest way to solve this is to move the DataTemplate from ResourceDictionary to your xaml file (where you have ItemsControl defined) and then set `Checked` event handler on the CheckBox in DataTemplate.

Your modified DataTemplate would look like:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UserDataTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=MyPhoto}" Height="100"/>
            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Path=Names}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <CheckBox x:Name="chkBxRegistered" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Checked="ChkBxRegistered_OnChecked"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

You can then write your checked handling logic in the event handler (in xaml.cs file):

```
private void ChkBxRegistered_OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Your checked handling code goes here
}
```