# How can I for each row in DataGrid generate checkbox or whatever just to select a multiple rows?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm working on small WPF app, I'm fetching data from a database and it looks like this:

```
public List<BillItemInSerie> GetSerialNumbers(BillItemsTemp stavka)
{
    List<BillItemInSerie> serialNumbers = new List<BillItemInSerie>();

    //serialNumbers = Controller.GetSerialFromDatabase();  // this is currently not working because I don't have any data in db

    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
    {
        BillItemInSerie serialNumber = new BillItemInSerie();
        serialNumber.ArticleId = i;
        serialNumber.ExpireDate = DateTime.Now;
        serialNumber.Lot = "Warehouse" + " " + i;
        serialNumber.Serial = "135" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + "/x";
        serialNumbers.Add(serialNumber);
    }

    dtgSerialNumbers.ItemsSource = serialNumbers;
    return serialNumbers;
}
```

As you can see I'm actually not getting it from a db because I don't have any rows in my tables, so I created by myself 10 objects to work with.

Here is my XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dtgSerialNumbers" SelectionUnit="FullRow" EnableColumnVirtualization = "True" EnableRowVirtualization ="True"  MaxWidth="4000" MaxHeight="2000" Background="White" Margin="5,5,5,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0"  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#0091EA" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#0091EA" CanUserAddRows="False" RowHeight="35" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="DataGridCentering"/>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{x:Static local:Globals.dataGridfontSizeHeader}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
           Color="LightBlue"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn         Binding="{Binding Serial}"      Header="Serial"     Foreground="Black"      FontSize="15"   FontFamily="Verdana" Width="20*"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn         Binding="{Binding Lot}"         Header="Desc."      Foreground="Black"      FontSize="15"   FontFamily="Verdana" Width="40*"   />
        <DataGridTextColumn         Binding="{Binding ExpireDate, StringFormat ={}{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}}"     FontSize="15"   Header="Date"   FontFamily="Verdana" Foreground="Black" Width="25*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn         Binding="{Binding IsSelected}"  Header="Select"     Foreground="Black"      FontSize="15"   FontFamily="Verdana" Width="15*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now I'm wondering how can I select corresponding ROWS, maybe somehow generate checkboxes next to each row and select a row by that?

Thanks 
EDIT:

After suggestions I've changed column to <`DataGridCheckBoxColumn`> instead of `DataGridTextColumn` and I've wrote this:

```
foreach (BillItemInSerie item in dtgSerialNumbers.ItemsSource)
            {
                if (((CheckBox)colSelektiraj.GetCellContent(item)).IsChecked == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(item.Lot.ToString());
                }
            }
```

It's basically for each selected row get value..

I'm not sure if this is right approach but I think it works.

Comment: you can use a DataGridCheckBoxColumn instead of DataGridTextColumn  for the Select column. Then add a trigger on IsSelected

Comment: @DanieleSartori I will give it a try, and even if I select a row by clicking checkbox how could I get a values in a code behind of selected rows?

Comment: You can already select multiple rows without having checkboxes. Try Ctrl+Click. Try different values of the SelectionMode property. Get multiple selected rows by the SelectedItems property.

Comment: Are you asking how to select the rows programmatically or by clicking on them?

Comment: @mm8 by clicking on them, and checking few of them if I would like to, but I did something and I'm not sure if it's right approach but here is what I've done, check for edit please.

Comment: Did you try @Clemens' suggestion?

Comment: @mm8 I've but that's not what I need, I need to click on a row by mouse and select it that way, and checkbox is there as orientation which rows are checked acctually, that's how that should work.

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: Please refer to my answer.

Comment: @mm8 I will in a sec, and how can I get selected values in a code behind ? Have you checked my Edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `SelectionMode` property of the `DataGrid` to `Extended` and add a `DataGridTemplateColumn`:

```
<DataGrid Name="dtgSerialNumbers" SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectionMode="Extended" ...>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Select">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Mode=TwoWay}" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Then you should be able to select several rows by pressing the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and click.

Comment: I would like to select multiple rows by clicking on a row and just setting IsChecked to true without holding CTRL, for example, click on row 1, click on row 5, just by simple click and that's it, that 2 rows should be selected and visually there would be indicator that they are selected in column with Header Select

Comment: How would you then deselect a row? This is not how a DataGrid works.

Comment: just by clicking again on it, IsChecked would become false, and I would get values of checked rows?

Comment: Is it possible to apply your solution without using CTRL ? Just by 'running' over data grid rows and selecting them by clicking on them?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: No. I am afraid that the `DataGrid` has no `Multiple` selection mode. If you don't need to be able to edit the data, you might want to consider using a `ListView`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try apply your solution also, it's clean and nice, but I'm wondering how to get selected rows value in my code behind?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: They should be in `dtgSerialNumbers.SelectedItems`.

Answer (score 0):

please take a look on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566050/executing-a-command-on-checkbox-checked-or-unchecked). in my eyes just put a checkbox inside of your datagdrid an bind the dataset ID to a command parameter like in this example

```
<CheckBox CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Id}"
          Command="{Binding DataContext.AddRemovePresetAssignmentCommand,
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                           AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
          Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
          >
```

then you have all possibilities in your viewmodel