# Interaction Trigger Command WPF MVVM not triggering

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik, telerik-grid

I am trying to bind **command** like below for a **checkbox** present in **RadGridView's Column Header**.

```
<telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="85" AutoSelectOnEdit="True" EditTriggers="CellClick">                                                
  <telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn.Header>
     <CheckBox Command="{Binding ShowAllInDTCClickedCommand}" Content="Sh">
         <i:Interaction.Triggers>
              <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">                                                                
                  <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowAllInDTCCheckedCommand}"/>
              </i:EventTrigger>
              <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">                                                                
                  <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowAllInDTCUncheckedCommand}"/>
              </i:EventTrigger>
         </i:Interaction.Triggers>
      </CheckBox>
   </telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn.Header>
</telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn>
```

And trying to **implement** them in **ViewModel** like below.

```
    public DelegateCommand ShowAllInDTClickedCommand { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand ShowAllInDTCCheckedCommand { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand ShowAllInDTCUncheckedCommand { get; set; }


    ShowAllInDTClickedCommand = new DelegateCommand(ShowAllInDTClicked);
    ShowAllInDTCCheckedCommand = new DelegateCommand(ShowAllInDTCChecked);
    ShowAllInDTCUncheckedCommand = new DelegateCommand(ShowAllInDTCUnchecked);

    private void ShowAllInDTClicked()
    {
        //Do Something
    }

    private void ShowAllInDTCChecked()
    {
        //Do Something
    }

    private void ShowAllInDTCUnchecked()
    {
        //Do Something
    }
```

But these **commands are not executing** i.e. code is not reachable at all.
What I am missing?

Comment: Basically, I am trying to check property of that column for all records present in the grid. something like 'Select All', 'DeSelect All'...

Comment: Have you bind your grid to a model?

Comment: Yes, I can populate objects, and everything else is working fine. Except these commands...

Comment: Judging from your comments to mm8 it sounds like there's a issue with your interactivity triggers. Maybe try this instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566050/executing-a-command-on-checkbox-checked-or-unchecked It seems like all you want is to find out the status of the checkbox and execute code accordingly so just passing that CommandParameter can give you that info.

Comment: Where do you make the assignment ShowAllInDTClickedCommand = new DelegateCommand(ShowAllInDTClicked); In the constructor or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, i am assigning in constructor

Comment: @user2619824 If you observe my question, I am already having that...

Comment: Look more closely. You have a command but no CommandParameter. Try it using the Parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If the `DelegateCommand` properties are defined in your view model, you should bind to them like this:

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowAllInDTCCheckedCommand, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:RadGridView}}"/>
</i:EventTrigger>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I modified the code same as you mentioned. But, it is not working.

Comment: So where are your commands defined and what's the DataContext of your RadGridView?

Comment: My commands defined in ViewModel. And I can trigger other commands bound in this XAML with the the same ViewModel

Comment: You didn't answer my question...What's the DataContext of the GridView? And what's the ItemsSource of the GridView? And what type is the commands in?

Comment: Datacontext is ViewModel. Other commands which are working are Button commands.

Comment: What button commands? Please edit your question and include all relevant parts.

Comment: Let's say I add a button to this XAML and bind command of that button to this Command (for e.g. ShowAllInDTCCheckedCommand), then it is working fine.

Comment: It depends on *where* you add the Button and what its DataContext is.

Comment: My XAML has Button and GridView. GridView has Columns. And one column has this checkbox. My XAML has ViewModel as Datacontext. If I have an observable collection in ViewModel, I can bind that to grid in my View. Could you please tell me now what will be the Datacontext to checkbox in ColHeader?

Comment: Not the view model. That's why you should use a RelativeSource when you bind to the command as I stated in my answer.

Comment: But it is not working as expected when I specify gridview as relativesource

Comment: Did you add "DataContext." to the binding path? What if you set AncestorType to Window or UserControl or whatever type your view is?

Comment: Yes, I added, still not working. and Yes, I also tried by adding 'UserControl' as ancestor type still no use.