# BindingExpression path error when binding to a check command of a Checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a `DataGrid` with a column of checkboxes and I have a checkbox in the `DataGrid` header that, when checked, checks all the checkboxes. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566050/executing-a-command-on-checkbox-checked-or-unchecked), I have a command bound to the "checked" event and another one that binds to the "unchecked" event.

All the relevant files are below (simplified, of course)

My XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="40">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <CheckBox>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CheckAllRowsCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UncheckAllRowsCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </CheckBox>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

My xaml.cs

```
public partial class MyTableView: UserControl
{
    public MyTableView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MyTableViewModel();
    }
}
```

**MyTableViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyTableViewModel: BaseViewModel
{
    public MyTableViewModel() : base()
    {
        CheckAllRowsCommand= new CheckAllRowsCommand(this);
        UncheckAllRowsCommand = new UncheckAllRowsCommand(this);
    }

    public ICommand CheckAllRowsCommand{ get; }
    public ICommand UncheckAllRowsCommand{ get; }
}
```

**CheckAllRowsCommand**

```
public class CheckAllRowsCommand: BaseCommand
{
    public CheckAllRowsCommand(MyTableViewModel parent) : base(parent)
    {
    }

    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
       // Set the Selected property of each data row
    }
}
```

When running this, I get the following error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'CheckAllRowsCommand' property not found on 'object' ''CheckBox'
>   (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=CheckAllRowsCommand;
>   DataItem='CheckBox' (Name=''); target element is 'InvokeCommandAction'
>   (HashCode=47015983); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

CheckAllRowsCommand is a property in a ViewModel, not in CheckBox. Try to bind to viewModel via DataGrid (it should have inherited the DataContext):

```
<DataGrid Name="NameOfDataGrid" ...>

<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.CheckAllRowsCommand, ElementName=NameOfDataGrid}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more verbose solution than ASh has posted but is more flexible, in my opinion.

```
<CheckBox DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
...
</CheckBox>
```

The problem is that the binding in the template seems to be using the `CheckBox` as it's data context when you would *think* it would use the data context of the containing control. WPF can be funky sometimes, an any time I see an error like this (ie `BindingExpression path error: 'blah' property not found on 'object' ''blah'`) I always assume the data context isn't being inferred correctly.

The workaround I'm proposing is to forcibly set the data context on the `CheckBox` using a relative source. Relative sources can be used to declaratively say "use the first parent of this type" for example. This binding is saying "set my DataContext property to the `DataContext` of the first parent above me of type `DataGrid`". Logically the first parent of that checkbox of type `DataGrid` is going to be the one you intended. Then your inner command bindings don't need to change and everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the `DataContext` of the `CheckBox` to the `DataContext` of the parent `UserControl` where the command properties are defined using a `{RelativeSource}`:

```
<CheckBox DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CheckAllRowsCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UncheckAllRowsCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
```